# BaseAdapter OnItemClickListener never called

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have a custom `BaseAdapter` for my `ListView` in which i implements `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

The problem is the `onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)` method is never called. I guess I need to implements that `interface` in my main `Activity` and not in my `ListView` custom adapter.

**MyListViewAdapter.java**:

```
public class MyListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<MyListViewRow> rowsList = new ArrayList<MyListViewRow>(); // All one row items

    private TextView a;


    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MyListViewRow> rowsList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowsList = rowsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.rowsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return this.rowsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new row to display in the list view.
     *
     * Position - position of the current row.
     *
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        /**
         * Inflating the root view and all his children and set them to a View Object.
         *
         */
        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row,null);

        // Get all the views in my row
        this.a = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.a_id;


        MyListViewRow myListViewRow = rowsList.get(position);

        // Set values to all the views in my row
        this.a.setText(myListViewRow.getA());



        return row;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onItemClick LV Adapter called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


} // End of MyListViewAdapter class
```

Am I right?

Comment: Did you call listView.setOnItemClickListener anywhere?  Without that it won't be called.

Comment: @GabeSechan No because i implement the `interface` in the `BaseAdapter` class.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything.  You have to call setOnItemClickListener or it will never be called.

Comment: onItemClick listener no needed.. you can use onclick listener in baseadapter or set onItemclick listener for your listview in your activity/fragment

Comment: @RanjithKumar What do i pass ass parameter for the `myListView.setOnItemClickListener`? And @USKMobility said i can't use `OnItemClickListener` with custom adapter. So which one of you is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you have an OnItemClickListener inside the Adapter?! Either you have OnClickListener inside the Adapter, or the best practice is to set OnItemClickListener to the ListView or whatever AdapterView you use in your activity/fragment. 
The way you are doing it right now, it won't work for several reasons:

1. You don't set the listener to the view.
2. You **CAN NOT** set an OnItemClickListener to a TextView.
3. Setting onClickListener to the TextView inside the adapter class, means that you will have to click the TextView itself, otherwise, the listener **WILL NOT** be invoked.

Comment: If i cannot set `OnItemClickListener` to a `TextView` so i will simply use the `OnClickListener`. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, but I would suggest you use OnItemClickListener on the ListView. Something like:
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
            // implement whatever you need to do here
        }
    };

Comment: Like what? if It don't apply on `TextView` It's worthless to me.

Comment: If you, for any reason, must set the onClick event to the TextView, than you should use OnClickListener on the TextView

Answer (score 1):

With custom adapter OnItemClickListener does not work. You must register onClickListener on view in getView method.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        /**
         * Inflating the root view and all his children and set them to a View Object.
         *
         */
        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row,null);

        // Get all the views in my row
        this.a = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.a_id;


        MyListViewRow myListViewRow = rowsList.get(position);

        // Set values to all the views in my row
        this.a.setText(myListViewRow.getA());
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    });


        return row;
    }
```

Comment: Why It's not working with custom adapter? I didn't saw any notation of that in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, its not mention in android doc. Click event conflict occurs. So OnIemClickListener does not work. You can try a trick to disable android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false" in all child view of row