# How to get TextView text in a cutom ListView and a custom BaseAdapter onClick(View) method

Tags: android, listview, textview, baseadapter

I have a custom `ListView` with 3 `TextView`s and a custom `BaseAdapter` which implements `View.OnClickListener`.

I tried some ways of getting the text from the specific `TextView` that has been clicked in the `onClick(View)` method but came out short.

If the `View` i get as the parameter of the `onClick(View)` method is the specific `TextView` that has been clicked , Why I can't get It's text properly?

**MyBaseAdapter.java**:

```
public class MyListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<MyListViewRow> rowsList = new ArrayList<MyListViewRow>(); // All one row items

    private TextView songYouTubeLink;
    private TextView b;
    private TextView c;

    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MyListViewRow> rowsList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowsList = rowsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.rowsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return this.rowsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new row to display in the list view.
     *
     * Position - position of the current row.
     *
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        /**
         * Inflating the root view and all his children and set them to a View Object.
         *
         */
        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row,null);

        // Get all the views in my row
        this.songYouTubeLink= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.songYouTubeLink_id);
        this.b = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.b_id);
        this.c = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.c_id);

        MyListViewRow myListViewRow = rowsList.get(position);

        // Set values to all the views in my row
        this.songYouTubeLink.setText(myListViewRow.getSongYouTubeLinkText());
        this.b.setText(myListViewRow.getB());
        this.c.setText(myListViewRow.getC());

        // Setting on click listeners
        this.songYouTubeLink.setOnClickListener(this);
        //this.b.setOnClickListener(this);

        return row;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onClick LV Adapter called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        Toast.makeText(context, tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, this.a.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

The first `Toast` in `onClick(View)` gives me "YouTube Link" `String` , and the second gives me a text from the 1 of the rows of the `ListView`(Note that the second `Toast` give me every time the same text until I browse my `LIsView`. After the browsing the first `Toast` stays the same and the second gives me a text of some other row `TextView`).

**EDIT**:

**list_view_row_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Artist name and song name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist_song_tv_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />

    <!-- Song youtube link -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_link_tv_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/artist_song_tv_id"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />

    <!-- Song shazam link -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shazam_link_tv_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/artist_song_tv_id"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/youtube_link_tv_id"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just set an onclick listener for the actual view instead of your Base Adapter implementing onclick?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast Because It's a more cleaner code this way.

Comment: Okay... Please upload what your "R.layout.list_view_row" xml looks like

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing onClick in your BaseAdapter is actually consuming the click of your row which is parent layout RelativeLayout in this case.

To get the actual textview, you should use:

TextView mView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id. artist_song_tv_id);

Then you can get the correct text.

Comment: I did that. But it gives me some row item `TextView` which i didn't clicked.

Comment: Are you using any view holder pattern?, its possible your adapter might be re-using the positions of the views and giving another value.

Comment: No view holder patter. The code I posted is the exact same code as I have. So I can make the adapter not to reuse the positions of the `View`s?

Comment: Actually. What you mentioned in your answer giving me a `NullPointerExcepion`.

Comment: Any idea why the `NullPointerException`? I really want to accept your answer.

Comment: Is the null pointer because of the view id or the text in the view, check both scenarios

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to do this

In your activity or fragment

```
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(hotelAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Hotel hotel = (Hotel) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

}

Comment: I tried `OnItemClickListener` , but someone in SO told me it will not work with a `TextView` so..

Comment: Sigh |: So why he told me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814378/baseadapter-onitemclicklistener-never-called I cant. (user3419782).